# Hibernate cannot open connection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc

I'm having trouble with hibernate not able to open a connection. I have a DAO:

```
public class MyDao extends HibernateDaoSupport
{
    DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public MyPOJO findByQuery(int hour)
    {
        Query query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM MyPOJO WHERE someDate >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL ? HOUR)")
        .addEntity(MyPOJO.class);

        List<MyPOJO> results = query.setInteger(0, hours).list();

        return results;
    }
}
```

and then in a test case call findByQuery(1) 8 times, it works, but if I call a 9th time it fails with:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Could not retrieve connection info from pool
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.datasources.SharedPoolDataSource.getPooledConnectionAndInfo(SharedPoolDataSource.java:169)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.datasources.InstanceKeyDataSource.getConnection(InstanceKeyDataSource.java:631)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.datasources.InstanceKeyDataSource.getConnection(InstanceKeyDataSource.java:615)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:827)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.datasources.SharedPoolDataSource.getPooledConnectionAndInfo(SharedPoolDataSource.java:165)
... 39 more
```

This is what my hibernate properties look like:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                thread
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

If I change the release_mode to 'after_statement' (ala http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#transactions-connection-release) it will work, but I don't understand that and feel like that is just a band-aid for something bigger that I am doing wrong.

I've also tried to flush and close the this.getSession() with no luck either. I can see the close() gets called AFTER all of the calls to findByQuery(1) have completed.

This is on Hibernate 3.2.6, Spring 3.0 and MySQL 5.1.
Let me know what more information I can provide.

Comment: isn't there a `Caused by` of the exception?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Javadoc for `HibernateDaoSupport.getSession()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html#getSession()) says:

> **Note that this is not meant to be
>   invoked from HibernateTemplate code
>   but rather just in plain Hibernate
>   code.** Either rely on a thread-bound
>   Session or use it in combination with
>   releaseSession(org.hibernate.Session).

So, the session obtained via `getSession()` should be released via `releaseSession()`:

```
public MyPOJO findByQuery(int hour) 
{ 
    Session s = null;
    try {
        s = this.getSession();
        Query query = s.createSQLQuery( 
        "SELECT * FROM MyPOJO WHERE someDate >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL ? HOUR)") 
        .addEntity(MyPOJO.class); 

        List<MyPOJO> results = query.setInteger(0, hours).list(); 

        return results; 
    } finally {
        if (s != null) this.releaseSession(s);
    }        
}
```

But the better way to deal with session is to use a `HibernateCallback`:

```
public MyPOJO findByQuery(int hour) 
{ 
    return this.getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<MyPOJO>>() {
        List<MyPOJO> doInHibernate(org.hibernate.Session session) {
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(    
                "SELECT * FROM MyPOJO WHERE someDate >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL ? HOUR)")    
                    .addEntity(MyPOJO.class);    
            return query.setInteger(0, hours).list();    
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ahh! I looked for ever for a way to do it via getHibernateTemplate(). Thanks a lot axtavt.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I would never have figured out why my application fails each 10 minutes when using `getSession()`..

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by updating the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` file.