# Hibernate Exception on running java Program run infinitely

Tags: java, hibernate, execution

**I have following requirements :**

I want my java program(core java , not webapp) to run continuously without stopping , and check the database entries , if there is any change then an alert should me made . I am using Timer for this , and hibernate to handle database . But after few successful iteration , I am getting the following exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1616)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
```

P.s : i have also used the following lines in my code , but it didn't worked

```
if (sess != null) {
        sess.clear(); // internal cache clear
    }

    Cache cache = factory.getCache();

    if (cache != null) {
        ( cache).evictCollectionRegions();
      // (cache).evictQueryRegions();
        (cache).evictDefaultQueryRegion();
        (cache).evictEntityRegions();
        // Evict data from all query regions.
    }

    sess.close();
```

Can someone please help me with this ? Thanks in advance .

*** and i am not using connection pooling**

Comment: can you try this, `if (sess != null) this.releaseSession(sess)`. Once you release the session next thread will be able to acquire the available sessions.

Comment: No eclipse is not recognizing this.releaseSession(sess)

Comment: can you add the code of how are you getting the session object. by using `getSession()` or any other way

Comment: I am doing this using single utility class , do you have any idea why i am getting this error ?

Comment: refer this so thread, it might help you -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469319/hibernate-cannot-open-connection